# I want to add css style to a particular node of lightning tree in my LWC. Is there any way to do so after my component loads and tree is generated?

Tags: lightning-web-components

**HTML File**

```
<template><lightning-tree items={items} header="Roles"></lightning-tree>   </template>`
```

**JS File**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc'; <br>

export default class TreeBasic extends LightningElement { <br>
    "items ="[<br>
   {<br>
      "label":"Western Sales Director",<br>
      "name":"1",<br>
      "expanded":true,<br>
      "items":[<br>
         {<br>
            "label":"Western Sales Manager",<br>
            "name":"2",<br>
            "expanded":true,<br>
            "items":[<br>
               {<br>
                  "label":"CA Sales Rep",<br>
                  "name":"3",<br>
                  "expanded":true,<br>
                  "items":[]
                  },<br>
               {<br>
                  "label":"OR Sales Rep",<br>
                  "name":"4",<br>
                  "expanded":true,<br>
                  "items":[]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't apply CSS to inner elements of a component. This is because of the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom). If you want to do something like this, you'll have to write your own custom component, and even then, you'll need to write the extra CSS/logic into the child component, again because of the Shadow DOM. It specifically restricts the ability of parents to modify the child elements' inner styles.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this using Aura components (without creating a custom component) ? I could apply styles to entire tree but not to the individual nodes.Is it a limitation of <lightning-tree> tag ?

Comment: @A.R Aura and LWC both still technically allows some leakage of CSS, but you should not depend on it working forever. Only a custom component will get you what you want in a future-proof way. Yes, the point of CSS isolation (Shadow DOM) is that each component is isolated from other developers so they will appear as the original developer intended. You can only style the component as a whole, not individual bits within. The entire component is a concrete unit.